# SMSS Formatting of characters

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, ssms

In SSMS 2005, If I inset the following character (‑) it changes the font of adjacent letters and I'm unsure why. It doesn't seem to have any adverse effect as it selects the data I want (which are parts of a order number) but I'd like to ensure that the character isn't altering the data in anyway. Is it just a visual change or are the characters actually changing?

[image]

```
SELECT 
'Hello',
'‑Hello',
'‑He110',
```

EDIT: Output when adding `N` as per the comments.

[image]

Comment: you forgot to say that your character is not usual minus sign (ASCII=45), and it has ASCII=63

Comment: It's unicode U+2011; non-breaking hyphen, try changing the font your using as it does not appear to be in courier/consolas

Comment: @teran - Thanks, Didn't know they were different.

Comment: @AlexK. The font is courier new. I tried courier but the adjacent letters still differ when placed next to the "‑". Is it just a visual thing?

Comment: you can `select` theese strings as unicode (`SELECT N'‑Hello'`) then they look fine in output table

Comment: I guess regardless of it the "‑" renders or not the important thing for me was that the "Hello" section of the second line is equal to the first line and not being modified by the "‑"